# Call a controller with multiple functions and cache this

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

I have a controller with 2 actions to show related products and related Boms of a product.

If I call first to related products function I have the related products but if I call now to related boms get the same result of last call ajax of related products.

If I call first to related boms I haven't items but if I call now to related products get the same result of last call, no data.

Is this Cahce issue ?

Any guide will be appreciated.

Comment: your question is not clear.
Can you show what you have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

Is a problem with cache system. I need to put this at the start of any function in my controller.

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
```